# create a set of UITextViews that are dynamically sized and laid out in place in relation to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I have a custom UIView where I want to layout a set of UITextView's in response to an AJAX call. So I think I will need to create these in code. I am currently setting the location to a fixed location but would rather set it to like 20pixels below the previous one. Also, I would like to set a minimum width of 650 pixels of my UITextView. I am using AutoLayout but am confused about the best way to achieve this. I have included my code but am really looking for what strategy is best to achieve this? Use AutoLayout constraints?

I have include how I'm currently doing it but would like to solve the dynamic verticasl placement and a fixed width of the UITextView's to 650points. Any help either in strategy or code would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [some count]; i++) {
    int my_counter=i+1;
    // this is obviously putting it a fixed location
    UITextView *textview= [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, (130 * my_counter), 650, 90)];
    [textview setScrollEnabled:YES];
    textview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    textview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [textview  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7)];
    NSString *tmp_header=[some[i] objectForKey:@"header"];
    NSString *tmp_body=[some[i] objectForKey:@"body"];

    //NSString *str = @"This is <font color='red'>simple</font>";
    if(![tmp_header isEqualToString:@""] && ![tmp_body isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSString *myString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", tmp_header, tmp_body];
        [textview setValue:myString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
    }
    if([tmp_header isEqualToString:@""] && ![tmp_body isEqualToString:@""]){
        [textview setValue:@"body is cool" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
    }

    textview.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    textview.editable = NO;
    textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"vardana" size:20.0];
    [textview sizeToFit];
    [textview setScrollEnabled:NO];
    //textview.contentSize.width=650;
    [self.noteView addSubview:textview];

}
```

[image: here's a sample layout of the objects - very straightforward]

Comment: i think best thing is to add constraints by code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, with this kind of problem you need to keep track of something outside the loop, to pass previous results to the next loop iteration. This code should work:

```
CGFloat runningYPosition = 130.f; // Y position of first text view
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Let's not care about the text view frame right now.
    // Let's just create, configure, populate, then set a frame based on contents/configuration.
    UITextView *textview= [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    textview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    textview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [textview  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7)];
    NSString *tmp_header=[some[i] objectForKey:@"header"];
    NSString *tmp_body=[some[i] objectForKey:@"body"];

    //NSString *str = @"This is <font color='red'>simple</font>";
    if(![tmp_header isEqualToString:@""] && ![tmp_body isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSString *myString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", tmp_header, tmp_body];
        [textview setValue:myString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
    }
    if([tmp_header isEqualToString:@""] && ![tmp_body isEqualToString:@""]){
        [textview setValue:@"body is cool" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
    }

    textview.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    textview.editable = NO;
    textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"vardana" size:20.0];

    // Set the text view frame
    CGSize textViewSize = [textview sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(650.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    textview.frame = CGRectMake(110.f, runningYPosition, textViewSize.width, textViewSize.height);

    [self.view addSubview:textview];

    // Update the running Y position for the next text view's frame, 20 pts below the current one.
    runningYPosition = CGRectGetMaxY(textview.frame) + 20.f;
}
```

Comment: thx - this is VERY helpful; I really appreciate it. this looks very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it as a UITableView. Each new item would be added to the tableview's data array and you could use [tableView reloadData] to display the new item.

You could then use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to adjust the height of each cell individually.